# How to use reset pin as I/O pin with ATtiny44

Tags: input, reset, programmer, arduinoisp

I am using the Arduino IDE as an ISP programmer to program my ATtiny44 IC. Unfortunately, I ran out of pins, so I want to use the reset pin as I/O. I read several articles online that says it is possible and even the datasheet says so.

[image]

I have a high voltage programmer as well. I wrote the code in the Arduino IDE and then used its hex file to program it using the high voltage programmer (TNM PROGRAMMER).

[image]

After I program, the IC stops working.

////////////////////////////////////EDIT/////////////////////////////////////

```cpp
const int led = 0;
const int reset_led = 11; //physical pin 4 on attiny

// the setup function runs once when you press reset or power the board
void setup() {
    // initialize digital pin LED_BUILTIN as an output.
    pinMode(led, OUTPUT);
    pinMode(reset_led, OUTPUT);
}

// the loop function runs over and over again forever
void loop() {
    digitalWrite(reset_led, HIGH);  // turn the LED on (HIGH is the voltage level)
    digitalWrite (led, HIGH);
    delay(1000);                    // wait for a second
    digitalWrite(reset_led, LOW);   // turn the LED off by making the voltage LOW
    digitalWrite(led, LOW);         // turn the LED off by making the voltage LOW
    delay(1000);                    // wait for a second
}
```

New fuse bit setup:

[image]

////////////////////////EDIT 2 /////////////////////////////////////////

[image]

Now, the led on reset has turned off completely while the another still blinks.
Powering my attiny44 with 5v.Code is same as before

////////////////////////////////EDIT 3////////////////////////////////////

```
#include <avr/io.h>
const int led = 0;
#define ledd PB3
// the setup function runs once when you press reset or power the board
void setup() {
  // initialize digital pin LED_BUILTIN as an output.
  pinMode(led, OUTPUT);
  
DDRB |= (uint8_t)(1<<PB3);
pinMode (ledd, OUTPUT);

}

// the loop function runs over and over again forever
void loop() {

PORTB |= (uint8_t)(1<< PB3);
 
 digitalWrite (led, HIGH);
  digitalWrite (ledd, HIGH);

 delay(1000);                       // wait for a second
 
PORTB &= ~((uint8_t)(1 << PB3)); // set PB3 to "low"
 
 digitalWrite(led, LOW);    // turn the LED off by making the voltage LOW
 delay(1000);                       // wait for a second
}
```

This code worked miraculously for me, Thanks to @thebusybee.

/////////////////////////////EDIT 3/////////////////////////////////////////

The PB3 pin is pin11 in arduino.

[image]

Comment: It sounds like you found the answer to what you're actually asking. *"After i program ( the ic stops working)."* The chip executes code irrespective of whether or not the reset function is enabled. So, your problem is elsewhere. I would look at whether or not I was staying out of the brownout detection and pay attention to what I was actually using as indication to determine that it "stops working" and maybe that will lead to a different question.

Comment: What do you mean by "_stops working_"?

Comment: If you are powering it by 3.6V (4.2V fully charged) battery, then with 4.3V BOD level it'll be held in reset state all the time (it might work a little if the battery is fully charged and you are lucky to have threshold deviation closer to 4V)

Comment: You could enable CKOUT fuse to have PB2 indicate that the clock is going. You appear to be forcing the watchdog timer to run and we're not seeing your code, which leads back to the question of how you're determining "stops working."

Comment: @timemage The reset pin is PB3. I have connected one led to the reset pin in order to indicate if it is working

Comment: @KIIV Yes, you are right, i did some research on it as well and changed my power to constant 5V but the led on the reset pin did not blink

Comment: @thebusybee It means that the led connected to reset pin goes off fully

Comment: @timemage As you can read my code above, there are two led on the board, the led on the reset stays on but looks like the voltage or current is extremely low due to which the led brightness is difficult to be seen (this led should be blinking as per the code). I connected the reset pin to potentiometer but the moment i change the value of pot the led connected to pin0 turns OFF or hangs.

Comment: Please take the [tour] to learn how this site works. It is not a forum. Please add clarification to your question by [edit]ing it. Down here in the comments it gets lost. -- If the LED on pin 0 stops blinking when you turn the pot's wiper towards GND, I'd say that the pin 11 is still /RESET. That would also explain the "glowing" of the LED at that pin too, because the pin is an input. Are you sure that your fuses are correct?

Comment: I am not 100% sure about the fusebits, Please check i have added new picture to the post above under edit @thebusybee The led at reset is also on (without blinking) but the brightness is extremely low

Comment: If _you_ are not sure about the fusebits, and the result seems to indicate that RSTDSBL is not set correctly, how can _we_ be sure and help you? ;-) Did you read the device's and the programmer's documentation at least three times to make sure you set the fuses correctly?

Comment: @thebusybee If you check above i have added screenshot of latest fuse bit setting. I have been using this HV programmer and attiny for long so I've idea the only new thing is that i have never before used RESET as GPIO. Just to confirm, RESET (PB3) is program pin 11.

Comment: As the data sheet () says: "_Pullup is activated and output driver and digital input are deactivated when the pin is used as the RESET pin._" What you see confirms that RSTDSBL is not programmed.

Comment: In my HV programmer there is option Disable Reset Pin (RSTDSBL) and we have two options to select (Yes or No). ofc if we have to disable it we must select "YES" and program it. Right?

Comment: Did you try the other option?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/142913/discussion-between-electro-nooobbbb-and-the-busybee).

Comment: I believe you meant trying "NO" option. Yes, i did, it didnt workout

Comment: *"The reset pin is PB3.*" I have no idea why you said that to me. Did your question get resolved or not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [data sheet](https://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/doc8006.pdf) gives insights:

Chapter 1.1.4 states:

> The reset pin can also be used as a (weak) I/O pin.

"*Weak*" means here, that the output function cannot deliver as much current as the other outputs, according to figures 21-24 to 21-27 beginning at page 198 roughly 2 to 3 mA. This is commonly not enough for LEDs, except you use a high-efficiency LED.

And on page 66 is this relevant table (I cut the irrelevant column for PB2):

> **Table 10-8.** Overriding Signals for Alternate Functions in PB[3:2]
>
> | Signal Name | PB3/RESET/dW/PCINT11 |
> | --- | --- |
> | PUOE | RSTDISBL<sup>(1)</sup> + DEBUGWIRE_ENABLE<sup>(2)</sup> |
> | PUOV | 1 |
> | DDOE | RSTDISBL<sup>(1)</sup> + DEBUGWIRE_ENABLE<sup>(2)</sup> |
> | DDOV | DEBUGWIRE_ENABLE<sup>(2)</sup> • debugWire Transmit |
> | PVOE | RSTDISBL<sup>(1)</sup> + DEBUGWIRE_ENABLE<sup>(2)</sup> |
> | PVOV | 0 |
> | PTOE | 0 |
> | DIEOE | RSTDISBL<sup>(1)</sup> + DEBUGWIRE_ENABLE<sup>(2)</sup> + PCINT11 • PCIE1 |
> | DIEOV | DEBUGWIRE_ENABLE<sup>(2)</sup> + (RSTDISBL<sup>(1)</sup> • PCINT11 • PCIE1) |
> | DI | dW/PCINT11 Input |
> | AIO |  |
>
> Note:
>
> 1. RSTDISBL is 1 when the Fuse is “0” (Programmed).
> 2. DebugWIRE is enabled when DWEN Fuse is programmed and Lock bits are unprogrammed.

Since you have `DebugWIRE` enabled, this seems to be the cause. The alternate function `RESET` is still active.

Please be aware that according to note 1 below table 19-4 on page 160:

> After programming the RSTDISBL fuse, high-voltage serial programming must be used to change fuses and allow further programming.

This means that your circuit at PB3 needs to withstand the high voltage, and that the voltage source needs to provide enough current, which the circuit additionally draws at the high voltage.

---

Now to your code.

You use the pin number "0" and hope to have PB3. Well, according to this shamelessly linked pinout this is not correct:

[image: Arduino pinout ATtiny44]

Pin "0" is PA0.

PB3 has no number assigned.

Your next step could be to look up the sources of the Arduino library and check, if PB3 has a number assigned at all. I'm afraid this is not the case. If you're lucky and it has, use it. You will want to tell us about your finding then.

You can directly access the data direction control register and the port register. Grab your data sheet and other documentation, read, and implement.

This is untested:

```c
// in setup():
    DDRB |= (uint8_t)(1U << 3);

// in loop():
    PORTB |= (uint8_t)(1U << 3);    // set PB3 to "high"
    PORTB &= ~((uint8_t)(1U << 3)); // set PB3 to "low"
```

Comment: Yes, i read it and is disabled it but it still did not work for me. After i make debugWire disable the reset led goes full off.

Comment: Well, that's a good sign, because now the pin became an output and went "low" (erm, how did you connect the LED?) or at least switched off the pull-up. Does the other LED still blink? -- BTW, your title says 44A but the prose 44. What exactly is it? (Correct your question.)

Comment: Oh that's a relief to know! Okay, so i have connected +ive of led directly to reset pin and -ive directly goes to GND of IC. Yes, with the new setup the other led still blinks.

Comment: Please **add** what you tried now to your question, and post the current fuses. If you changed the sketch, please add it, too.

Comment: Done, edit 2. The code is same as before reset programmable pin11

Comment: Would you mind to clarify which device it is, 44A or 44?

Comment: The device is attiny44 not attiny44A. I mentioned in edit2 above

Comment: OK, so your title misled me. I have corrected it. Now I need to fetch the other data sheet and to check out the differences. :-( This will need some time, I have some other work to do.

Comment: ok.no prob, i checked they are almost the same just some memory size difference is there.

Comment: Right. I edited my answer concerning page numbers and such. However, since I don't have an ATtiny44 I cannot check in real. Currently it should work as your fuses are set, I'd say.

Comment: ok, i have 44A , i tried with that it still does not work. Please recheck my fusebits the spien, boden or maybe my pin declaration has some issues

Comment: See my edit, your code is wrong. I assumed you checked that already. Just a hint: don't program "by random", development is more science than art.

Comment: OMG, it is working with your code. Thank you so much, but why do we need to write high and low in that manner, it should work with simple coding as well because in the future i have to declare this pin as one of my antenna pins, how do i do that?  (#define CSN 0)
This command i have to write for PB3. i have to declare CSN PIN of antenna to pb3

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/142922/discussion-between-electro-nooobbbb-and-the-busybee).

Comment: I have just posted my code above.

Comment: If the pin has no number assigned by the Arduino library, you cannot use the common functions. That's what I wrote in my answer. "If you have no legs, you cannot walk." However, you're free to implement your own work-around. -- Please consider to mark the answer as "accepted".

Comment: I have accepted. Arduino library has assigned it as pin 11 (PB3 is pin 11) but if we code it, it does not work. I think it is because of the digitalWrite function i will try changing that function and update u tommorow

Comment: Not every Arduino model has pin number 11 assigned to PB3, I found multiple different assignments. Make sure you look at the correct model!

Comment: I rechecked PB3 is pin 11 for arduino UNO board. I have attached picture above

Comment: Sure, the Uno has this. But you use a ATtiny44, the Uno has the ATmega328P.

Comment: ATtiny44 also declared reset pin as pin11 but if you code it that way it is always rejected. (#define CSN 2 ) this is my antenna pin which i want to shift to the reset pin. i can use avr language to it but how do i declare it.

Comment: No, according to the pinout, "RESET" has no pin number assigned for the ATtiny44. Where did you find that? -- Since the programming issue is another beast, feel free to post a new question. You might want to add a link to that in your question.

Comment: Ok i will create new link

Comment: https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/92300/how-to-declare-pb3-reset-pin-or-attiny44-in-program-using-arduino-ide-platform